# Java 1.6 and URIBuilder

Tags: java, apache, uri, uribuilder

There is a clean way to build this examples with Apache URIBuilder?

```
"http://host/path", passing "path2" -> "http://host/path/path2"
"http://host/path", passing "/path2" -> "http://host/path2"
```

"resolve" method is not working, it always return:

```
http://host/path2
```

Thanks.

Comment: True, i was wrong. I mean using URI from java.net.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a trailing slash on your baseurl.

```
new java.net.URI("http://host/path/").resolve("path2");  // http://host/path/path2
new java.net.URI("http://host/path/").resolve("/path2"); // http://host/path2
```

Without the trailing slash `path` will not be handled as directory. Than it does not matter if you resolve a absolute or relative `path2` because they are resolved against `host/`